# InvocationTargetException when trying to invoke method from .jar in Android

Tags: java, android, jar

I'm using an android application and a simple java application which are using same methods. So i've encapsulated these methods in another project that I export in a .jar file.

When i'm using this .jar in the simple java application, there is no problems. It works fine.

But when I'm using this .jar in Android, I get a "InvocationTargetException".
My .jar is compiled in 1.6 because i've heard that Android doesn't support 1.7

The simple creation of a new instance and the exceptions occurs...

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

An **InvocationTargetException** comes from **reflection**, and means the Method that was invoked threw an Exception. Do you see any sign of another stack trace that might be the underlying Exception? If not, try catching InvocationTargetException and looking at getCause() to see what is really going on.

Comment: Unfortunately the exception doesn't reach the catch clause. The application stops directly.

It happens for every method that I try to call. Even a simple "new()" with the default constructor.